# Validate multiple subarray's content PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would know how can I remove the empty value from the array I am creating from BD, I tried using the function array_filter like I saw in another questions, but got no lucky...

Could you tell me how to remove?

Here is the code that generates the array:

```
while($row = $stm->fetch()) {

    if ($row['id_tipo_profissional'] == '1') {
    //CRIA ARRAY DE DADOS DO TIPO PROFISSIONAL 1

        $id_tipo_profissional_1 =   $row['id_tipo_profissional'];
        $tipo_profissional_1    =   $row['tipo_profissional'];

        $profissionais_1[] = [
            'id_profissional' => $row['id'],
            'nome' => ucwords($row['nome'] . ' ' . $row['sobrenome'])
        ];

    } else if ($row['id_tipo_profissional'] == '2') {
    //CRIA ARRAY DE DADOS DO TIPO PROFISSIONAL 2

        $id_tipo_profissional_2 =   $row['id_tipo_profissional'];
        $tipo_profissional_2    =   $row['tipo_profissional'];

        $profissionais_2[] = [
            'id_profissional' => $row['id'],
            'nome' => ucwords($row['nome_do_escritorio'])
        ];

    }
}


$resultado =  array_filter([
    "tipo" => [
            $id_tipo_profissional_1 => [
                'id_tipo_profissional'      =>  $id_tipo_profissional_1,
                'nome_tipo_profissional'    =>  $tipo_profissional_1,
                "profissionais"             =>  $profissionais_1
            ],


            $id_tipo_profissional_2 => [
                'id_tipo_profissional'      =>  $id_tipo_profissional_2,
                'nome_tipo_profissional'    =>  $tipo_profissional_2,
                "profissionais"             =>  $profissionais_2
            ],
    ],
]);

return json_encode($resultado);
```

With this output:

```
{
  "tipo": {
    "1": {
      "id_tipo_profissional": "1",
      "nome_tipo_profissional": "advogado",
      "profissionais": [
        {
          "id_profissional": "22",
          "nome": "Joao Abreu"
        }
      ]
    },
    "": {
      "id_tipo_profissional": null,
      "nome_tipo_profissional": null,
      "profissionais": null
    }
  }
}
```

But this my desire output when the array is empty (using this data as an example):

```
{
  "tipo": {
    "1": {
      "id_tipo_profissional": "1",
      "nome_tipo_profissional": "advogado",
      "profissionais": [
        {
          "id_profissional": "22",
          "nome": "Joao Abreu"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what if `id_tipo_profissional` is null and others not null?

Comment: Its impossible in the context on my data, if "id_tipo_profissional" is null all the others inside will be null too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditionals :

```
$typo = [];

if($id_tipo_profissional_1){
    $typo[$id_tipo_profissional_1] = [
        'id_tipo_profissional'      =>  $id_tipo_profissional_1,
        'nome_tipo_profissional'    =>  $tipo_profissional_1,
        "profissionais"             =>  $profissionais_1
    ];
}

 if($id_tipo_profissional_2){
    $typo[$id_tipo_profissional_2] = [
        'id_tipo_profissional'      =>  $id_tipo_profissional_2,
        'nome_tipo_profissional'    =>  $tipo_profissional_2,
        "profissionais"             =>  $profissionais_2
    ];
}

$resultado['typo'] = $typo;
```

Comment: I am testing here hehe, thanks alot for your time